# Docker compose mysql connection failing

Tags: python, mysql, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run 2 docker containers using docker-compose and connect mysql container to app container.Mysql container is running but app container is failing to start with the error **Error:2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:3306' (111 Connection refused)**
It seems like my app container is trying to connect my host mysql instead of mysql container.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: database
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: malicious
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root

  app:
    build: .
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - .:/Docker_compose_app   #app directory
    depends_on:
     - "mysql"
    command: [ "python", "database_update.py"]
    restart: unless-restart
    environment:
    # Environment variables to configure the app on startup.
     MYSQL_DATABASE: malicious
     MYSQL_HOST: database
```

**Dockerfile**

```
 FROM python:2.7
 ADD . /Docker_compose_app
 WORKDIR /Docker_compose_app
 RUN apt-get update
 RUN pip install --requirement requirement.txt
```

This is my **database_update.py** file.

```
    def create_TB(cursor,connection): 
      query = '''CREATE TABLE {}(malicious VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL)'''.format("url_lookup")
      cursor.execute(query)
      connection.commit()

    def connection():           
     try:
       cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user="root",password = 'root',database=malicious)
       cursor = cnx.cursor()
       create_TB(cursor,cnx)

     except mysql.connector.errors.Error as err:
       data = {"There is an issue in connection to DB":"Error:  {}".format(err)}
```

Comment: Maybe mysql need some time to start? Try sleep 10-30 seconds before start connection from your app

Comment: but it won't resolve the issue because even after mysql container comes up,app container still gives the same error.I used restrat: unless-restarted with app conatiner

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues I can see:

1. Try to add

   ```
   links: 
     - mysql:mysql
   ```

   to the `app` service in your Docker Compose file. This will make sure that you can reach the `mysql` container from `app`. It will set up a hostname mapping (DNS) in your `app` container, so when you `ping mysql` from `app`, it will resolve it to the `mysql` container's IP address.
2. In your `.py` file, where are you defining which host to connect to? Add `host="mysql"` to the `connect` call. By default, it will connect to `127.0.0.1`, which is what you're seeing.

   ```
   cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host="mysql", user="root", password = 'root', database=malicious)
   ```

Fixing both of these should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks it resolved the issue.But I am trying to understand how my app container is able to connect mysql connector without specifying port?I mean i haven't specify port or expose mysql port.

Comment: The MySQL container automatically exposes port 3306 (the default port), and the Python MySQL Connector uses 3306 as a default value. If you used a different port, you could provide it using an additional `port=XXX` parameter in your `connect` call.

Comment: Added this steps, still the same error. Connection resolves the name 'mysql' to an IP but wont able to connect(

Comment: @Sultan1991 did you manage to fix it? I'm also having trouble with this

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using Docker Networks.

I was having a similar problem while having two seperate Python container connecting to one mysql-Container, while those 2 were connected to a Vue-Frontend.

First I tried using links (which was not optimal, because the communication-flow is not entirely linear), just like you but the I ran across this great post:
https://www.cbtnuggets.com/blog/devops/how-to-share-a-mysql-db-with-multiple-docker-containers

Using Networks shift the port mapping off and lets you enhance your overall App-Architecture.

Therefore I think you should try something like:

```
services:
  python-app:
    networks:
      - network_name
    ...
  
  mysql:
    networks:
      - network_name
    ...

networks:
  network_name:
```